# How to calculate the execution time of one query in stored procedure on oracle

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Good Morning .

I got stuck in sql query . Please can you help me here.

problem statement: I have to calculate the execution time of one query in stored procedure.

There are about 150 queries in stored procedure and  I have to store this execution time in one table . please help me  here .

Because of some confidentiality, I cant provide the data.
please find dummy data

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test (p_fromdate DATE)
AS
   fromdate   DATE;
   todate     DATE;
   c1 number;
   c2 number;
   c3 number;
BEGIN
   fromdate := p_fromdate;
   todate := p_fromdate;

 select count(*) into c1 from employee;
 select count(*) into c1 from mngr;
 select count(*) into c1 from hr;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      ROLLBACK;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (   SQLERRM
                            || '~'
                            || 'Data not populated for'
                            || p_fromdate
                           );
END test;
```

Comment: you can always provide dummy data. without data how we suppose to help you

Comment: Provided more details above